# Restore conda/pip freeze consistency

Tags: python, pip, conda

Until now I was managing my Python envs with conda and was using:

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

when needed for deployment purposes.

But I ended up doing `pip install some_package` for some package I could not install with conda (which was apparently a terrible idea) and now `pip freeze` result has become totally unrelated to whichever conda environment I am activating.

Is there a way I can restore the situation, meaning having `pip freeze` correctly describe the conda environment that is currently active?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem following:
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1429#issuecomment-320117143

The main idea is to install pip in your conda env before doing any pip install and then deactivating conda before using it. In details:

**Step 1**:
Deactivate conda

```
conda deactivate
```

repeatedly until no longer in a conda env
(nothing in parentheses to the left of your prompt)
or use

```
source deactivate (deprecated but still works)
```

Then

**Step 2**:

```
conda activate your_environment
conda install pip
which pip
=> /home/sunless/miniconda3/bin/conda (global version)
pip freeze
=> still your global packages
```

**Step 3**:
Deactivate your env again (same as step 1)

**Step 4**:

```
conda activate your_environment
which pip
=> /home/sunless/miniconda3/envs/your_environment/bin/pip (local version)
pip freeze
=> your local packages
```

Answer (score 1):

When using both pip and conda I would recommend using `conda env export > environment.yml`. This will create a yml file with the versions you are using including where to find them and how to install them.

When you need to install the enviroment on a new machine, you can use `conda env create -f environment.yml`

Note: the yml file also dictates what the environment will be called. This can be changed manually in the file before installing the environment though.

Comment: The problem is that for deployment purposes I do need to produce a ``requirements.txt`` as the remote environment is not building using conda (sadly). So I still need to have a way to ``pip freeze`` in a way that is consistent with the active conda env.

Comment: Okay, in that case I'm not aware of any solution except rebuilding the environment from scratch and making sure you first install all conda packages and then install all pip packages. It's recommended to rebuild your environment each time you need to use conda install after already using pip install to prevent unstable situations. This is because conda is not aware of the changes made by pip and may break things by overwriting.